# Mapping of a struct missing field

Tags: arrays, struct

I have an interface.

```
interface IAuction {
    struct Auctioneer {
        uint256 a;
        uint256 b;
        bool c;
        address d;
        uint256 e;
        uint256 f;
        string[] bids;
    }
}
```

and a contract that implements the interface.

```
contract Auction is IAuction {

  mapping(address => Auctioneer) public auctions;

  string[] encryptedBids;

  function register(
        uint256 start,
        uint256 end
    ) external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "You did not specify the payment!");
        auctions[msg.sender] = Auctioneer(
            msg.value,
            0,
            true,
            address(0),
            start,
            end,
           encryptedBids
        );
    }
  }
```

I use remix interface to register auction with dummy arguments; however, when I check `auctions` map I don't see the encryptedBids argument. It does show `Auction` struct has 6 field rather than 7. Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I belive it is because bids is string[].
Just like mapping, it it accessable only by KEY you provide,
but [ ] is accesable by index.
It probably has to do with how Remix is implemented to show array and mapping data...
You should probably have some function like:

```
function getBidsAtIndex(uint index) public view returns(string memory)
{
    return auctions[msg.sender].bids[index];
}
```

For accessing that data.

Hope it helps.